# Composer Download Error (openssl)

Tags: php, windows, installation, composer-php

[image: Composer install error]

I wanted to install composer on my other computer. I have encountered this question before but none of the answers seem to work for me.

I tried enabling the openssl package in php.ini but it is already enabled. i tried changing the include path in my php.ini file. I reinstalled mamp . But none of the above fix the problem.
[image]

[image]

i'm using php 5.6.8

Comment: Is there openssl in you phpinfo?

Comment: yes, i checked it with the command prompt. it's active

Comment: Is it possible there are two php application in your computer? And is there any php-cli.ini in your file system?

Comment: i had Xampp installed before , but i uninstalled it to install MAMP PRO, but i made sure that the xampp php.exe was removed completly. The odd thing is that if you look at the last screenshot. Configuration file path is at c:\windows, but the loaded config file has another path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by putting the php.ini file in the c:\windows file, it's a messy solution but it works. I can't use MAMP PRO anymore for some reason it keeps crashing, but it works on MAMP and i installed composer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take the following steps to make sure that the openssl extension gets loaded:

1. determine where your PHP is: open a command prompt, then `php --ini`.
2. find under "Loaded Configuration File" the path to the active `php.ini`
3. make sure this `php.ini` has `extension=php_openssl.dll`

I think you either have multiple PHP version installed and the Composer installer picks the one, where you didn't modify the php.ini or starts php without an php.ini.

(There are server stacks for windows with composer support out of the box, like [wpn-xm](http://wpn-xm.org/). Sorry, shameless plug.)

Comment: like i said in my question i already did those steps you mentioned . and i get the same result

Comment: If you do the steps you clearly see, which PHP and which configuration file is used. Its basically a debugging helper. I think you either have multiple PHP version installed and the Composer installer picks the one, where you didn't modify the php.ini or starts php without an php.ini.